# I am trying to work with this library pyModeS, but stuck in errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed a library called `pymodeS` to decode the ADSB messages, but while running the `modeslive` command, as per the readme document some error messages are popping up and I unable to resolve them.

This is the link: https://github.com/junzis/pyModeS/blob/master/README.rst

```
# modeslive --help
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py:13: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import fnmatch, glob, traceback, errno, sys, atexit, locale, imp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/modeslive", line 12, in <module>
    from pyModeS.streamer.source import NetSource, RtlSdrSource
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyModeS/streamer/source.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyModeS.extra.rtlreader import RtlReader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyModeS/extra/rtlreader.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rtlsdr import RtlSdr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rtlsdr/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .librtlsdr import librtlsdr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rtlsdr/librtlsdr.py", line 61, in <module>
    f = librtlsdr.rtlsdr_get_device_count
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)`

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))

AttributeError: /usr/bin/python3: undefined symbol: rtlsdr_get_device_count
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the installation command from pip install pyModeS to pip3 install pyModeS, now it shows the following issues

```
enter code here
modeslive -h
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py:13: DeprecationWarning: the imp module 
is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative 
uses
import fnmatch, glob, traceback, errno, sys, atexit, locale, imp
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/modeslive", line 12, in <module>
from pyModeS.streamer.source import NetSource, RtlSdrSource
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyModeS/streamer/source.py", line 3, in 
<module>
 from pyModeS.extra.rtlreader import RtlReader
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyModeS/extra/rtlreader.py", line 4, in 
<module>
from rtlsdr import RtlSdr
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rtlsdr/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
from .librtlsdr import librtlsdr
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rtlsdr/librtlsdr.py", line 61, in 
<module>
f = librtlsdr.rtlsdr_get_device_count
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /usr/bin/python3: undefined symbol: rtlsdr_get_device_count
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in mac. Have you installed *librtlsdr* ? `brew install librtlsdr`